# bad signature using gpg to verify Ubuntu download

Tags: ubuntu, gnupg

GPG gave a "BAD signature" response when verifying a downloaded Ubuntu ISO image after following the Ubuntu desktop download verification [steps](https://stackoverflow.com). I got the same response (below) when re-downloading everything, following the steps again after using gpg --delete-key.

I was expecting a a "Good signature" response from GPG, but instead got:

```
gpg: Signature made Mon Jul 17 11:25:28 2023 BST
gpg:                using RSA key 843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: BAD signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" [unknown]
```

I doubt that the download has been corrupted or tampered with, but I'd still like to positively verify the downloaded file with a "Good signature" response from GPG.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, so this is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You might be able to ask on [ubuntu.se] instead, but check out [their How to Ask page](//askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) to confirm.

Comment: Thanks will create a new one on ask Ubunutu